# Extraction of specific report in GA4 (Google Analytics 4)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to use GA-4 and extract data. In the console, I can find multiple reports created with different names. All of the reports have the same "Metrics" and "dimensions". I need to extract the data from a specific report through python that I would then use to push into the DB.

Can you help me identify the way to extract specific report based-data from the GA-4 console? I am currently trying to do using the property-id and have also tried exploring the filtering on the "Query Explorer" provided in the documentation. However, that is pulling data from all the reports.

Say for example, if I have

Report 1: Number of Active users: 123
Report 2: Number of Active users: 345

When I use the query explorer and say I want "Active" users.
It gives: 468.

I want to use python to get users from only "Report 1" : 123